# Add mail to Send folder with SwiftMailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I'm using SwiftMailer for PHP from [swiftmailer.org](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Everything works well but I wonder if there is a way to add the sent message into the sent folder from the mail account that SwiftMailer is sending from?

That's all, have a nice day.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the developer, swiftmailer cannot copy to Sent folder because it is a mail sender and not mailbox manager.

As mentioned on the [github page](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/202):

> Swiftmailer is a library to send emails, not to manage mailboxes. So, this is indeed out of the scope of Swiftmailer.

However, someone from php.net posted [a solution that might work for you](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-append.php#111461):

1. Use SwiftMailer to send the message via PHP.

   ```
   $message = Swift_Message::newInstance("Subject goes here");
   // (then add from, to, body, attachments etc)
   $result = $mailer->send($message);
   ```
2. When you construct the message in step 1) above save it to a variable as follows:

   ```
   $msg = $message->toString(); 
   //  (this creates the full MIME message required for imap_append()!!
   //  After this you can call imap_append like this:
   imap_append($imap_conn,$mail_box,$msg."\r\n","\\Seen");
   ```

Answer (score 8):

I've had similar problem and Sutandiono's answer got me into right direction. However because of completeness and as I had additional problem connecting to an Exchange 2007 server, I wanted to provide a complete snippet for storing message to Sent folder on IMAP:

```
$msg = $message->toString();
// $message is instance of Swift_Message from SwiftMailer

$stream = imap_open("{mail.XXXXX.org/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "username", "password", null, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI'));
// connect to IMAP SSL (port 993) without Kerberos and no certificate validation

imap_append($stream,"{mail.XXXXX.org/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Sent Items",$msg."\r\n","\\Seen");
// Saves message to Sent folder and marks it as read

imap_close($stream);
// Close connection to the server when you're done
```

Replace server hostname, username and password with your own information.