# Store emails sent with laravel in sent folder with IMAP

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, imap

I want when I send an email with laravel this appears on my sent email box in roundcube. I know Laravel uses SMTP and this doesn't work like this. I need some way to do it. I found that possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497557/add-mail-to-send-folder-with-swiftmailer) but I dont know how can I apply it to my code.

I use Laravel 5.2 and I send emails like this:

```
    $config = array(
        'driver' => 'smtp',
        'host' => 'smtp.example.es',
        'port' => '25',
        'from' => array('address' => 'email@example.es', 'name' => 'BILL'),
        'encryption' => '',
        'username' => 'email@example.es',
        'password' => '123456',
        'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        'pretend' => false
    );
    Config::set('mail',$config);

    Mail::send('emails.bill', array(
        'name' => $customer->name, 'lastname' => $customer->lastname,
        'concept' => $bill->concept  ), function($message) use ($data)
    {
        $message->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get8BitEncoding());
        $message->to($data['email'])->subject('BILL - '.$data['concept']);
        $message->attach($data['doc']);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This could serve you :)

```
//INI PARA GUARDR EN LA CARPETA DE ENVIADOS
            /* First, retrieve a raw copy of the message */
            $msg_raw = "body raw";

            /* Open an IMAP connection to your server, use config, env... whatever */
            $stream = imap_open(
                "{".config('mail.host')."/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}",
                config('mail.username'),
                config('mail.password'),
                null,
                1,
                ['DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI']
            );

            /* Store the email as Seen (or not) into your sent folder, use config, env... whatever */
            imap_append(
                $stream,
                "{".config('mail.host')."/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}" . config('mail.imap_sent'),
                $msg_raw."\r\n",
                "\\Seen" /* just empty if you prefer Unseen */
            );

            /* Close the stream, cleanup */
            imap_close($stream);
            //FIN PARA GUARDR EN LA CARPETA DE ENVIADOS
```